# variable min_value in a decimal field form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to set the min_value of a field's form variable.

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bid'] = forms.DecimalField(min_value=50, 
                            error_messages={'min_value': 'Price must be greater than the current price'}) 
        self.fields['bid'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Place your bid here', 'step': 1})
```

I have harcoded the 50 value in this case, but what I need is to set it according to the current bid.

This is the Bid, User and Auction models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Auction(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    base_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="auctions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("detail", args=[self.slug])

class Bid(models.Model):
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="bid", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction, related_name="bid", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Bid for ${self.bid} on {self.auction} by {self.user}'
```

This is the view:

```
def detail(request, auction):
    auction = get_object_or_404(Auction, slug=auction)
    comments = auction.comments.all()
    current_bid = auction.bid.last()

    comment_message = None
    bid_message = None
    new_comment = None
    new_bid = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        bid_form = BidForm(data=request.POST)
        if request.POST.get("form_type") == 'form_comment':
            bid_form = BidForm()
            if not request.user.is_authenticated:
                comment_message = "You have to sign in to post a comment"
            else:
                if comment_form.is_valid():
                    new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                    new_comment.auction = auction
                    new_comment.user = request.user
                    new_comment.save()
                    return redirect('detail', auction.slug)
        elif request.POST.get("form_type") == 'form_bid':
            comment_form = CommentForm()
            if not request.user.is_authenticated:
                bid_message = "You have to sign in to place a bid"
            else:
                if bid_form.is_valid():
                    new_bid = bid_form.save(commit=False)
                    new_bid.auction = auction
                    new_bid.user = request.user
                    print(bid_form)
                    new_bid.save()
                    return redirect('detail', auction.slug)
    else: 
        comment_form = CommentForm()
        bid_form = BidForm()

    context = {'auction': auction, 
               'comments': comments, 
               'comment_form': comment_form, 
               'bid_form': bid_form,
               'new_comment': new_comment, 
               'new_bid': new_bid,
               'current_bid': current_bid,
               'comment_message': comment_message,
               'bid_message': bid_message
               }
               
    return render(request, 'auctions/detail.html', context)
```

And the form in the tempate:

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="form_bid">
                <div class="msg">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        {{bid_form.bid}}
                        {% comment %} 
                                <input type="number" id="id_bid" name="bid" 
                                min="{{current_bid.bid|add:1}}"> 
                        {% endcomment %}
                        {% if bid_form.bid.errors %}
                            {{bid_form.bid.errors}}
                        {% endif %} 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group send-reset">
                    <input type="submit" value="Place Bid"/>
                </div>
            </form>
```

`{{bid_form.bid}}` renders as
`<input type="number" name="bid" min="50" step="1" placeholder="Place your bid here" required>`
but I need it renders as

```
<input type="number" id="id_bid" name="bid" min="{{current_bid.bid|add:1}}">
```

The last one works on client side, but I cann't figure it ou how to implement it on server side.
Any help would be appreciated!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: ```<input type="number" id="id_bid" name="bid" min="{{current_bid.bid}}"> ``` Are you try this ?

Comment: yes, that works only with browser validation, but it didn't rise a validation error on Django if I add novalidate on the form.

Comment: I also tried with self.fields['bid'] = forms.DecimalField(min_value="{{current_bid.bid|add:1}}" . It renders well but i get en error: '<' not supported between instances of 'decimal.Decimal' and 'str' when I submit the form...

Comment: please add User,Auction this model.

Comment: Thanks Riyas! I added the other models.

Comment: I finally solved it by adding the following at the view: `elif float(request.POST['bid']) <= current_bid.bid:
                bid_message = "Your bid must be greater than the current price"`

Comment: You got answer ??

Comment: yes, but by adding the validation in the view, not in the field form...thanks!